# Perl and open3. What am I missing?

Tags: perl, mplayer

I'm trying to make a script that communicates with mplayer using open3, but the mplayer process is showing up as defunct and I am unable to send standard input into mplayer.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

{
    package mplayer::test;
    use IPC::Open3;

    sub new {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self = bless { @_ }, $class;
        $self->start_mplayer();
        $self;
    }

    sub start_mplayer{
        my $self = shift;
        local *DEVNULL;
        open DEVNULL, ">/dev/null" or die "/dev/null: $!";
        open OUTPUT, ">out.log" or die "out.log: $!";
        $self->{r} = local *MPLAYER_READ;
        $self->{w} = local *MPLAYER_WRITE;
        $self->{pid} = open3($self->{w},$self->{r},">&DEVNULL",'mplayer -slave -idle -v');
        die "Error opening mplayer!\n" unless $self->{pid};
    }
    sub do{
        my ($self, $command) = @_;
        print {$self->{w}} $command, "\n";
    }
}

mplayer::test->new;

mplayer::test->do(qq~loadfile test.mp3~);
sleep(5);
```

I must be missing something obvious, I'm learning open3 from examples from other modules.

Comment: `">&DEVNULL"` should be `\*DEVNULL` ?

Comment: Get rid of `$self->{r} = local *MPLAYER_READ; $self->{w} = local *MPLAYER_WRITE;` If it doesn't help, it'll at least get rid of two useless lines.

Comment: I had no idea local returned a value.

Answer (score 1):

First off, switch to [lexical filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).  Typeglobs are package global and difficult to work with.

One problem is with `local *DEVNULL`.  You've made `*DEVNULL` local to `start_mplayer` (and whatever it calls, including `open3`), but then used the associated filehandles *outside* `start_mplayer`.  By that time, `*DEVNULL` has reverted back to its global state (ie. empty) and `open3` tries to write to an empty filehandle.  You should have gotten a `print() on unopened filehandle DEVNULL` warning, but you don't have warnings on...

Solution: don't localize it.  Unfortunately this means you can't have multiple mplayer instances running at once.  Normally you'd solve this by using a lexical filehandle, but unfortunately the special `>&` syntax only works with glob handles.  The solution is to only open DEVNULL once.

Alternatively you can let `open3` write to an error filehandle and just ignore them.  Wastes a miniscule amount of memory.

Other changes...

- Turn on strict and warnings
- OUTPUT is never used.
- Breaking up the command into multiple args avoids possible shell interference.
- Putting localized filehandles into the object beforehand is unnecessary.
- autodie is easier than typing "or die ..." all the time.

Here's your reworked `start_mplayer` routine.  I don't have a copy of mplayer to try it with, but it works fine with `cat`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

sub start_mplayer{
    my $self = shift;

    # Only open DEVNULL once, since its going to be shared.
    open DEVNULL, ">", /dev/null" unless fileno DEVNULL;

    $self->{pid} = open3($self->{r}, $self->{w}, ">&DEVNULL", 'mplayer', '-slave', '-idle', '-v');

    die "Error opening mplayer!\n" unless $self->{pid};
}
```

To determine if its your program or something weird about mplayer, try a different command, like 'cat'.  Often you have to close the input, or make sure it sees a newline, before a program will produce output.

For a more robust way to interact with programs, see [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun).